# Using private registry docker images in Kubernetes when launched using docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, docker-stack

I have a simple `docker-compose` file like the following:

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
  mongo:
    image: asia.gcr.io/myproj/mymongo:latest
    hostname: mongo
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: $MONGO_DB_DATA
        target: /data/db
    command: [ "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0", "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB", "1.5"]
```

I am launching it in Kubernetes using the following command

```
docker-compose config | docker stack deploy    --orchestrator kubernetes --compose-file - mystack
```

However, when the pod fails with this error

```
Failed to pull image "asia.gcr.io/myproj/mymongo:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

My private registry is the gcloud one. I have already logged in docker like the following using the service account keyfile.

```
docker login  -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://asia.gcr.io
```

The image is pulled correctly when I run

```
docker-compose pull
```

From this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/, I found that I need to create `ImagePullSecrets`

I have two questions.

1. How can I write the `ImagePullSecrets` syntax in my docker-compose so that it is referred correctly.
2. The method that the links mentions asks you to use `.docker/config.json` file. However, my config.json has

   "auths": {
           "asia.gcr.io": {},
       },
   It doesn't include the username and password since I configured it using the keyfile. How can I do this?
3. Or is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: create based on existing credential ```kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson```

Comment: YOu can alos make from command line `kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>` 

2. Refer this secret in your yaml as `spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred`

Comment: by `yaml` you mean `docker-compose.yml`? I don't have any `yaml` for deployments.

Comment: Yes , try like mentioned here

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets-configuration-reference

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by first creating a secret like this

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server https://<docker registry>  --docker-username _json_key --docker-password <json key> --docker-email=<email>
```

and then adding it to the default service account

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "regcred"}]}'
```